# Win vs won, lose vs lost

Tags: expressions, verbs

Right after a game, is there any difference whether if one says "I win" or "I won", or "I lose" or "I lost."  I know people usually say "I win!" Do people also say "I lose." right after the game?

Comment: If you are still “in the moment” you can say either.